# python unittest xml files created in different folder when test fails

Tags: python, xml, unit-testing

The following code results in the log file printed to different folders depending on whether the test passes or not.  I have a test case with one test purpose.  During the running of the test, it does a chdir().

If the test result is fail (an assert* fails), the xml file is written to the test's current directory.  If the test result is pass, then the xml file is written to the start folder.  See the code snippet for how I specify the log file folder.  Other than using full paths, is there a way to make python unittest always write it to the start folder?

```
logFolderName = "TestMyStuff_detail-" +str(scriptPid)
unittest.main(testRunner=xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(output=logFolderName),
              failfast=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Other than using full paths, is there a way to make python unittest always write it to the start folder?

Doubtful since relative paths will always be relative to the current working directory.  If your test changes the current working directory, you're kind of out of luck.

With that said, it shouldn't be too hard to use a full path:

```
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
localLogFolderName = "TestMyStuff_detail-" +str(scriptPid)
logFolderName = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(cwd, localLogFolderName))
```

Comment: Thanks.  Just seems odd that the xml file location is determined by the cwd at the time of failure, rather than using the cwd at the time the test purpose ends, which is what happens for a passing test purpose that does a cd as well.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a fixed path to write your output. 
Something like

```
path_to_my_output_folder="/path/to/output/"

test1_write_xml(path_to_my_output_folder+"file1.xml")
test2_write_xml(path_to_my_output_folder+"file2.xml")
test3_write_xml(path_to_my_output_folder+"file3.xml")
```